# measure processing time of multiple AJAX calls at the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In this way I can measure the processing time of mine ajax call

```
var ajaxTime= new Date().getTime();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
}).done(function () {
    var totalTime = new Date().getTime()-ajaxTime;
    // Here I want to get the how long it took to load some.php and use it further
});
```

but, how can I do if I want get the processing time for multiple ajax call at the same page?

I mean something like this:

```
var i;
var j = 5;
for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
var ajaxTime= new Date().getTime();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
}).done(function () {
    var totalTime = new Date().getTime()-ajaxTime;
    // Here I want to get the how long it took to load some.php and use it further
});
}
```

I need to know the response time for each call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that there's [no block scope in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17311693/497356), so `ajaxTime` is not redeclared on every loop iteration (it's set to whatever the current time is on each iteration). You can refactor your `$.ajax` code into a function or use a closure so that a new `ajaxTime` variable is used for every request:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    makeRequest(i);
}

function makeRequest(i) {
    var ajaxTime = new Date().getTime();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'some.php',
        type: 'POST'
    }).done(function () {
        var total = new Date().getTime() - ajaxTime;
        console.log('Elapsed time: ' + total);
    });
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Y9MJk/1/