# Javascript - Why are declarations in exclusive if clauses considered duplicate?

Tags: javascript, scope

With the following JavaScript

```
if (someCondition){
   var x = ...; //Resharper warns that this is a duplicate declaration
}
else {
   var x = ...; //Resharper warns that this is a duplicate declaration
}
```

But the scopes are different? Why does this matter? Is this exclusive to JavaScript?

I get no such warning with equivalent code in C#.

Or -- Is it an erroneous Resharper warning?

Comment: Javascript does not have block scope. All declarations of `x` belong to the function in which they are declared. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311693/why-does-javascript-not-have-block-scope

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variables in JavaScript are by default bound to function scope, not to block scope. Variables defined inside blocks are hoisted to function scope, which is a very common source of errors. and exactly what happens in your case too.

[Variables can be declared in block scope with `let` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) although this requires JavaScript 1.7.

Comment: Well that makes sense, I'll accept the answer when timer elapses.