# Passing Object in javascript function - Object is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am passing Object to another function but I am getting `"Obj Undefined error". I have referred from this http://jsfiddle.net/F6FxB/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="panel accordion clearfix" id="dispdir">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            showFolders([{
                "folderName": "eod-balance-summary",
                "objects": [{
                    "keyName": "eod-balance-formatted-2014-06-01.csv",
                    "keyValue": "eod-balance-summary/eod-balance-formatted-2014-06-01.csv"
                }],
                "childDirs": []
            }, {
                "folderName": "reconciliation-activity-summary",
                "objects": [{
                    "keyName": "recon-summary-2014-04-01-2014-04-02.csv",
                    "keyValue": "reconciliation-activity-summary/recon-summary-2014-04-01-2014-04-02.csv"
                }],
                "childDirs": []
            }]);
        };
    </script>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
folderId = 1;

function showFolders(folderList) {
    var markup = "";
    $("#dispdir").append("<ul>");
    for (var i = 0; i < folderList.length; i++) {
        var fid = "folder_" + folderId;
        markup = "<li id='" + fid + "'>" + folderList[i].folderName + "</li>";
        $("#dispdir").append(markup);
        $("#" + fid).on("click", function () {
            showJson(folderList[i]);
        });
        folderId += 1;
    }
    $("#dispdir").append("</ul>");
}

function showJson(Obj) {
    alert(Obj.folderName);
}
```

Comment: Where is the JSON? You don't have any JSON, you have an array. It doesn't need parsing ...

Comment: The code seems to work just fine on your fiddle, for me.

Comment: See, the HTML Code it is being sent as an argument

Comment: He said he referred the fiddle... I think its not his fiddle

Comment: @ShaunakD - It's one of the arguments of the function `showFolders`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work because of this line: `showJson(folderList[i]);`

`i` has the same value as `folderList.length`. Since this line is execute when the element is clicked, `i`'s value has already been changed by the loop. [There is no block scop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311693/why-does-javascript-not-have-block-scope)e in JavaScript. Because `i` is the same as the length of the array, `folderList[i]` would be `undefined`. When it gets passed to `showJson`, `Obj` would then be `undefined`.

To fix this, simply wrap it with an anonymous function.

```
$("#" + fid).on("click",
    (function(i){
        return function(){
            showJson(folderList[i]);
        };
    })(i)
);
```

---

In [JavaScript 1.7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) though, there are block scopes:

```
for(let i = 0; i < folderList.length; i++){
    let j = i;
    $("#" + fid).on("click", function(){
        showJson(folderList[j]);
    });
}
```

Comment: You have syntax error in your first code, please fix this

Comment: Just add "}" before ")(i); line 6 of your code and that will work"

Comment: Erm... `let` still has the same issue as `var` in your example... E.g. in open in Firefox to see the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/aLsyc/

Answer (score 1):

You can't use variable "i" inside the click function. since when you click on a div element i has finally updated value i.e 2 since your array has 2 element. So set data to the element itself and retrieve this data later when click on the element. For Ex:

```
function showFolders( folderList ) {

    $("#dispdir").append("<ul>");
    for ( var i = 0; i < folderList.length; i++ ) {
         var fid = "folder_"+folderId;
         var markup = $("<li id='" + fid + "'>" + folderList[i].folderName + "</li>");
         $(markup).attr("metadata",folderList[i].folderName);

         $("#dispdir").append(markup);   
         $(markup).click(function(){          
            showJson($(this));
         });

         folderId += 1;
    }
    $("#dispdir").append("</ul>");
}

function showJson( Obj ) {
    alert($(Obj).attr("metadata"));   
}
```