# 3D Lines disappear sometimes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, 3d, three.js

I am building 3d line chart from data

here is the code [Demo](http://ameetrana.yzi.me/demos/lines/)

the part of code that generate line is

```
     parentTransform = new THREE.Object3D();
            var _color = d3.scale.category10();
            for (var i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
                var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
                    // color: 0x0000ff,linewidth: 30
                     color: _color(i), linewidth: 50
                });
                var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;

                var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
                var k = -10;
                    for (var j = 0; j < 80; j=j+10) {
                        var _x = j;
                        var _y = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - 10 + 1)) + 10);
                        var _z = i*5;

                        geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(_x,_y,_z));
                        var _point = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.8);
                        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: _color(i)} );
                        var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( _point, material );
                        sphere.position.set(_x,_y,_z);
                        parentTransform.add( sphere );
                    };           
                var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
                line.material.linewidth = 2;
                parentTransform.add(line);
            };
            scene.add( parentTransform );
```

**Sometime When I start to rotate/zoom line disappear**.. only point stay there

also I wanted to add 3 axis walls any help ? 
I have experience with d3.js and new at Three.js so 
any help will be most welcome

Comment: can you post an image of what you mean disappear because I don't see it. it works fine for me.

Comment: Look at demo it not totally disappear on next move it come back but some other live hide

Comment: change the last two arguments of your camera definition to 0.1, 1000. Is your scene bigger than 1000?

Comment: Nop it just line chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining the variable `material` in two places, and consequently you are passing `MeshBasicMaterial` instead of `LineBasicMaterial` to the `THREE.Line` constructor.

three.js r.71

Comment: well that may be right but the the var inside for loop should't stay in that scope ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311693/why-was-block-scope-not-originally-implemented-in-javascript.

Comment: Yes sure any way I need to make axis with line ,text and tick any known link ?